# Is there an ordinal setting in High Charts for Android / iOS?

Tags: highcharts, android-highcharts

I've come up across an issue which I cannot seem to solve on Android and iOS.

I have a chart that plots data which has the x-axis as a date time. The issue I'm having is that the data I have only has data points during a working week (i.e. Monday - Friday), weekends result in no data.

Here's an example to highlight the issue I'm facing:

[image: Chart example]

I'd like the points to be equally spaced and the periods without any data **not** to be shown as a gap.

After searching a bit I've found out that High Charts for web has an `ordinal` property which specifies the gap between each point. ([Documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.ordinal)).

I'm wondering whether there's a similar property in the High Charts for Android and iOS as I couldn't find any information regarding the `ordinal` property in either High Charts Android or iOS documentation.

Comment: I haven't seen options ordinal at the android documentation https://api.highcharts.com/android/highcharts/, but this option is reserved for Highcharts Stock that could be the reason.